# 'GPR' object has no attribute 'X'

Tags: python, gpflow

I am trying to run the code from https://github.com/befelix/safe_learning/blob/master/examples/1d_example.ipynb . This code is written for gpflow version 0.4.0. I want to update this code for gpflow version 2.5.2. I changed the following line

```
gp = gpflow.gpr.GPR(np.empty((0, 2), dtype=safe_learning.config.np_dtype),
                    np.empty((0, 1), dtype=safe_learning.config.np_dtype),
                    kernel,
                    mean_function=mean_function)
```

to

```
gp = gpflow.models.GPR(data=(np.empty((0, 2), dtype=safe_learning.config.np_dtype),
                    np.empty((0, 1), dtype=safe_learning.config.np_dtype)),
                    kernel=kernel,
                    mean_function=mean_function)
```

then it creates a class object,
`dynamics = safe_learning.GaussianProcess(gp, name='gp_dynamics')`
which is defined as follows:

```
    """A GaussianProcess model based on gpflow.

    Parameters
    ----------
    gaussian_process : instance of gpflow.models.GPModel
        The Gaussian process model.
    beta : float
        The scaling factor for the standard deviation to create
        confidence intervals.

    
    """

    def __init__(self, gaussian_process, beta=2., name='gaussian_process'):
        """Initialization."""
        super(GaussianProcess, self).__init__(name=name)

        with tf.variable_scope(self.scope_name):
            self.n_dim = gaussian_process.X.shape[-1]
            self.gaussian_process = gaussian_process
            self.beta = float(beta)

            self.input_dim = gaussian_process.X.shape[1]
            self.output_dim = gaussian_process.Y.shape[1]

            self.hyperparameters = [tf.placeholder(config.dtype, [None])]
            self.gaussian_process.make_tf_array(self.hyperparameters[0])

            self.update_feed_dict()
...
```

when I run this class, I get the following error

```
dynamics = safe_learning.GaussianProcess(gp, name='gp_dynamics')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Input In [39] in <cell line: 1>
    dynamics = safe_learning.GaussianProcess(gp, name='gp_dynamics')

  File D:\python\safe_learning-master\safe_learning-master\safe_learning\functions.py:490 in __init__
    self.n_dim = gaussian_process.X.shape[-1]

AttributeError: 'GPR' object has no attribute 'X'
```

Please kindly help me how this attribute has changed in new version (2.5.2) of gpflow. I am using the following link to upgrade https://gpflow.github.io/GPflow/develop/notebooks/gpflow2_upgrade_guide.html#Model-Class

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's a big difference between `0.4.0` and `2.5.2`. I don't think you should expect this to be an easy process.

`model.X` and `model.Y` has been replaced with `model.data[0]` and `model.data[1]` respectively. In fact `model.data` corresponds to the `data` parameter you passed to the `GPR` initialiser.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Changing to data[0], data[1] is working. I am getting couple of issues similar to above. For example, "'GPR' object has no attribute 'make_tf_array'". Can you suggest any link that list out the changes? Though it is not an easy process, it is a requirement for me to make it run. Thank you.

Comment: I'm afraid you're asking for change over too long time. You're asking for the difference between now and 5 years ago, and that covers two major versions. We had an [upgrade guide](https://gpflow.github.io/GPflow/2.4.0/notebooks/gpflow2_upgrade_guide.html) from version `1.x.x` to `2.x.x`, but even that is deprecated. We also have a [change log](https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/blob/develop/RELEASE.md), but that only goes back to version `2.1.5`. I'm sorry. I think you're going to have to dive into the source code and really understand GPflow, if you want to make this kind of update.